Why does data in Room database sometimes not appear, but then comes back randomly after restarting?
A few users of my Android app have reported that sometimes the data on the local database is missing. However, it appears that the data also comes back even after this. One user actually sent me videos of when there is no data in the local trips view screen and then all the past data is mysteriously back after he opened the app again later.
Provided some code snippets below showing how i am using Room. Please help find any issues with what i am doing. Somehow, i feel like there are different database instances being created. But I am not sure how exactly its happening.
Dao:
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import xxx.TripData
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface TripsDao {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addTrip(trip: TripData)

@Update
suspend fun updateTrip(trip: TripData)

@Query("UPDATE trips SET is_online = :isOnlinePayment WHERE tripId = :tripId")
suspend fun setOnlinePaymentStatus(tripId: String, isOnlinePayment: Boolean)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteTrip(trip: TripData)

@Query("SELECT * FROM trips ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getMostRecentTrip(): TripData?

@Query("SELECT * FROM trips")
suspend fun getAllTrips(): List<TripData>

@Query("SELECT * FROM trips")
fun getAllTripsFlow(): Flow<List<TripData>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE tripId = :tripId")
suspend fun getTrip(tripId: String): TripData?

@Query("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE end_time IS NULL ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1")
fun getLatestOnGoingTripFlow(): Flow<TripData?>

@Query("DELETE FROM trips")
suspend fun clearAllTrips()

}

Module:
import android.content.Context
import xxx.LocalTripsRoomDatabase
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): LocalTripsRoomDatabase {
        return LocalTripsRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTripsDao(database: LocalTripsRoomDatabase) = database.tripsDao()
}

Database:
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import xxx.TripsDao
import xxx.TripData
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.asExecutor

@Database(entities = [TripData::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class LocalTripsRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun tripsDao(): TripsDao

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "local_trips_db"

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: LocalTripsRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): LocalTripsRoomDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context = context.applicationContext,
                    LocalTripsRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                ).setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .setQueryCallback({ sqlQuery, bindArgs ->
                        Log.d("LocalTripsRoomDatabase", "Query: $sqlQuery - Args: $bindArgs")
                    }, Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                Log.d("LocalTripsRoomDatabase", "getInstance - instance created: $instance - context ${context.applicationContext}")
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}

Repository
import xxx.TripsDao
import xxx.TripData
import xxx.IoDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

class LocalTripsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @IoDispatcher private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
    private val tripsDao: TripsDao
) : LocalTripsRepository {
    override fun addTrip(tripData: TripData) {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            tripsDao.addTrip(tripData)
        }
    }

    override fun updateTrip(tripData: TripData) {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            tripsDao.updateTrip(tripData)
        }
    }

    override fun setOnlinePaymentStatus(tripId: String, isOnlinePayment: Boolean) {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            tripsDao.setOnlinePaymentStatus(tripId, isOnlinePayment)
        }
    }

    override fun deleteTrip(tripData: TripData) {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            tripsDao.deleteTrip(tripData)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getMostRecentCompletedTrip(): TripData {
        return tripsDao.getMostRecentTrip() ?: throw Exception("No trips found")
    }

    override suspend fun getAllTrips(): List<TripData> {
        return tripsDao.getAllTrips()
    }

    override fun getAllTripsFlow(): Flow<List<TripData>> {
        return tripsDao.getAllTripsFlow()
    }

    override suspend fun getTrip(tripId: String): TripData? {
        return tripsDao.getTrip(tripId)
    }

    override suspend fun getLatestOnGoingTripFlow(): Flow<TripData?> {
        return tripsDao.getLatestOnGoingTripFlow()
    }

    override suspend fun clearAllTrips() {
        CoroutineScope(ioDispatcher).launch {
            tripsDao.clearAllTrips()
        }
    }

}


This is most likely caused by inconsistent UI updates.
From your DAO I see that you already employ flows to always get the latest data, but you don't do that with all query methods. Especially getMostRecentTrip and getAllTrips look like they should always be updated automatically, not only on request.
Since you didn't share how the data from the DAO is actually displayed in the UI I assume that you can fix the rest from here on: Pass through/transform the new flows in the view model and let the UI collect the flows to always be up-to-date.

I have changed all the query methods to return flows. Will update the latest changes in production and then wait for users to share any feedback. Thank you!
